# Count and column name in same query

Tags: sql

My query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT alloc.[code4]) AS countcode4,code4, table2.itemid  as tbitemid2   
   FROM table1,table 2
WHERE table1.id=table2.id
GROUP BY code4, tbitemid2
```

I want the query to give me the count and return only 1 instance of 'code4'

How do I do this?

Thanks
Mithil

Answer (score 0):

Remove `code4] from the`group by`, and use an aggregation functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT alloc.[code4]) AS countcode4, min(code4) as code4,
       table2.itemid  as tbitemid2   
FROM table1 join
     table2
     on table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY tbitemid2;
```

I don't know what `alloc` is; it is from your sample query.